# Consume inputstream of java.lang.Process twice

Tags: java, inputstream

I have a method which constructs a java.lang.Process instance and starts a process. Inside the method, I'd like to call `process.getInputStream().transferTo(System.out);` to observe how process is doing:

```
public Process doSth(List<String> command, File workdir) {
    Process process = new ProcessBuilder(command).directory(workdir).start();
    //redirect process's input stream to stdout to observe
    process.getInputStream().transferTo(System.out);
    ...
    return process;
}
```

But throughout the codebase, there are calls to `process.getInputStream()` to parse the process's text output, such as:

```
public void doSomethingWithProcessOutput() {
    Process process = doSth(...); // call to the method above
    InputStream stream = process.getInputStream();
    String processResult = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
        .lines()
        .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));

    //do something with the processResult string
}
```

Now if I want to observe the process by transferring the input stream to System.out, it consumes the stream, therefore subsequent calls to `process.getInputStream()` returns empty.

How can I both print the stream to System:out, but also re-read it when needed in other places? I tried to wrap the process' input stream with `org.apache.commons.io.input.ObservableInputStream` but it also consumes the stream.

Comment: You can add a step `lines().map(line -> ...)` where action prints line and returns line

Comment: It’s worth studying the alternative ways of [How do I read / convert an InputStream into a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/309424/2711488), as splitting the input into line strings, just to reassemble them to a single string, is not the most efficient approach…